# advanced search using PHP

Tags: php, postgresql, search

am trying to make a query to Postgres data base using PHP, the fields names are written in Arabic, the problem that the arabic letters accepts different combinations in writing, so if i want to make the query with what ever combination written by the user to make the correct query....iam using th following query in my code:

```
$query = "SELECT name,state,locality,auname,pauname,ST_AsText(the_geom) AS the_geom FROM morganweb.sudanfullattributespoi WHERE name LIKE '%" . $text . "%';";
```

but it doesnot seem to do the correct functionality..and its not also an arabic letters problem...its about if the user typed the place name, the query will not work unless the user wrote the same exact phrase in the data base...so can anyone help me in this?

Comment: Some examples of user input and stored data would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The `%` is a wildcard meaning "zero or more other characters". So "%ale%" will match "ale", "male", "ales", "males", "asasasasasale", etc. It doesn't mean it will accept letters in different combinations as you mention in the OP.

Comment: what about solving the capital letters problem? if i wrote the word in capital letters the query fails ??? also in arabic letters we have different combinations for the words  for example (مدرسة and مدرسه) have u noticed the difference in the last letter of the arabic word...well i want my code to understand this differences and to make the query right

Comment: Use `COLLATE` to enforce a case-insensitive character set. And, no, I don't see the difference in the last letter. I don't read Arabic. Also, MySQL doesn't understand the semantics of a word, only the syntax of its byte(s). If Arabic words can be spelt in two or more different ways then you're going to have difficulty with this. You'll need a PHP script to work out all the different variations of the given word and then check each individually in the query.

Comment: yeah that what i mean..i have differences in the spellings, and user can type it in any of them ..and that my problem here..is that the search using PHP should be more predictive !

Comment: No it shouldn't. PHP doesn't understand the meaning of language. Only people do. We're a long way from artificial intelligence. The only way it can emulate this is by having an in-built dictionary. Try building one of your own if you want.